# How to skip the "_" in like %% clausure , Sybase IQ

Tags: sql, sql-like, sap-iq

Task: find all the Views that start with "vf_"

The code should be:

```
 select * from systable where table_type = 'VIEW' and table_name like 'vf_%'
```

The Problem is that the database use the " _ " like a joker , that means that in the " _ " could come every sign.

thats why is returning me

vf_
vfa
vfg
..
..

How could I say to database that i just want the views that start for "vf_" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Gordon's suggestion of using an escape character ...

You can search for the underscore as a string (as opposed to a wildcard character) by placing the underscore inside a pair of square brackets, eg:

```
select * from systable where table_type = 'VIEW' and table_name like 'vf[_]%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `escape` option if you like:

```
table_name like 'vf$_%' escape '$'
```

There is a default escape character, the backslash:

```
table_name like 'vf\_%'
```

However, years of moving between Windows-based and Unix-based operating systems makes me really wary of backslashes.

There are alternatives, such as:

```
left(table_name, 3) = 'vf_'
```

Comment: @MBijen . . . See, me and backslashes just don't get along ;)